# Css - Preventing scrollbar width to be included in the content width

Tags: css, reactjs, scrollbar

I'm having this problem with a scrollbar, I want the width of the scrollbar to be extra of the content's width.
for example, i have a div with 64px width, and if there is a scrollbar, the width of the div + the width of the scrollbar becomes 64px.

How can i do it?